# rotate Image on openGL

Tags: opengl, rotation

I am loading a model on opengl.
when I save the model to a tiff file, I can see it as a mirror pic of the X axis .

How can I change it so I can see it as it loads on OpenGL?

how can I fix it so I can see my model in the irfan View as I see it in the openGL?
when I open irfan View my model is seen like a mirror toward down...

Thanks

Comment: apply a scaling matrix (prior to all other matrix) with negative value on the axe to revert before saving your model example: scale(-1,1,1) would suite your needs.

Comment: do you mean :glScalef(-1,1,1);?

Comment: yes,its in float. Thats what I am doing but I dont get any change in the model. I want it to rotate -90 in the X axis so I will accept the real Image(because my model begins from top left with Y axis going down)

Comment: 90°? so scaling will not be the answer. not sure i understand clearly what you want to achieve.